# Using Toggle PopUp Functionality in ArcGIS API for JavaScript?

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I've look through every example on Stack GIS.Stackexchange which might deal with my problem. Of course there was good input, but unfortunately I'm not able to fix it.

Admittedly my JavaScript skills are not the best, so "easy" thing are also very hard to overcome.

Until now I've stuck at the following level: http://jsfiddle.net/84vvR/

I'm using nliu's TOC http://gmaps-utility-gis.googlecode.com/svn/tags/agsjs/latest/examples/toc.html and the editor and popup functionalities overed by esri's API.

As you can see, theoretically all work. The mapapp contains an editor an the option for popup.

However, if the user wants to add new features by clicking on the map, the popup pops out and gives information about the underlying area, which has the defined popup. The same problem, if the user want to use the measurement tool. On the first click, the popup pops out and so it's not possible to add a starting point for measurement.

I've tried to implement a workaround with dojo.connect and a clickHandler or onClick like (button dojoType=”dijit.form.Button” onClick=”....(),...();”>Disable Popup Function

I assume that it's not too hard for an advanced developer to solve this problem to bind the Popup Functionality to a checkbox or Button.

Answer (score 1):

As of API 3.10, you can call `setInfoWindowOnClick` in `esri/map` and pass in true or false.

See: https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/map-amd.html#setinfowindowonclick

You can either attach that to a toggle check box or just make it when user clicks add new feature, the program disables info window automatically.